# Intuition on why does $P(-1) = 0$ leads to identify one factor of a 3rd Degree Polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, intuition, factoring

Given $P(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 -13x -15$

In order to detect occasions in which $P(x)=0$, the factors of the remainder $15$ i.e. $\{-1,-3,-5,1,3,5\}$ were used as values of $x$

These were: $P(-1)$, $P(3)$ and $P(-5)$

Ok. Cool.

Now I know that this equation is the same as $(x-1)(x+3)(x-5)$. This, of course, can bring the standard form back.

```
Edit-1: Ok! he above is wrong. Sorry (:
```

**This also has factors $(x+1)(x-3)(x+5)$**

I just didn't quite get why that is!

I know it works, I just don't seen to understand why the "x with opposite signal" is called factor of this polynomial. I believe my question is more about intuition than method.

Yes, I know that in order to make the equation equal to zero I need $x=1$ OR $x-3$ OR $x=-5$ above. But why do I even care about making it equal to zero? Why is it important to find the linear factors? Is it just a matter of simplification for further complexity? Is it because I can find the x-intercepts? Where is this leading me?

Anyone has any tips that might help the concept to hit me? I'm reviewing maths. I learned how to pass exams in the past, but now I am on a journey to learn real maths.

Thanks a lot

Comment: The form (x-1)(x+3)(x-5) is NOT correct! The correct factorization is (x+1)(x-3)(x+5). Basically, if P(a) = 0 where P is any polynomial and a is a real number then (x-a) will be a factor of P. Here, P(-1) = 0 so (x-(-1)) = (x-1) is a factor. Why? See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem

Comment: > But why do I care about making it equal to zero? 

Because you are trying to solve an equation? I don't know why you are interested solving the particular equation but as long as that's your goal, then making it equal to zero is the first step. 

As far as the maths, it is just a Bezout's theorem. Namely, if a polynomial $P(x)$ satisfies $P(a)  = 0,$ then it factors as $P(x) = (x-a)*Q(x),$ for another polynomial $Q(x).$ You can prove it using Euclidean algorithm, but the intuition itself should be obvious

Comment: Try multiplying out your first factorisation. If $p(a)=0$ then $x-a$ is a factor - the division algorithm gives $p(a)=(x-a)q(a)+b$ and setting $x=a$ gives $b=0$.

Comment: Note that, in plugging in those values of $x$, what you're doing is testing for possible _rational_ roots of $P(x)=0$. In this case, all the roots are rational and so you find all of them. But it's not hard to come up with polynomials that have integer coefficients and no rational roots, e.g. $x^2-x-1=0$.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal - Check that I put both forms. One as the linear factor and another as the factorization. That's exactly what I'm trying to understand...

Comment: @dezdichado really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: By the **Factor Theorem** $\ f= (x\!+\!a)g\,$ for some $\,g\!\iff\! f(\color{#c00}{-a}) = 0.\,$  Note $\color{#c00}{\text{minus}}$ sign in  root $\,x = \color{#c00}{-a}$ $\ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P(-1)=0$, then $P$ has some factor which is zero when $x=-1$. Which is to say $P$ has some factor which is zero when $x+1=0$. Which is to say it has $(x+1)$ as a factor.

It is this moving of the root from one side of the $=$ to the other which causes or to change into the opposite sign. Equivalently, we want the factor to be $0$ when $x$ has a specific value, which means we are forced to *subtract* that value from $x$ to make it $0$, which flips the sign.

Your $(x-1)(x+3)(x-5)$ doesn't bring the standard form back,  as that becomes $x^3-3x-13+15$, which is not the same thing.

Comment: Ah! Ok. Now I understand my confusion. It was a "typo" on my notes.

Answer (score 0):

Had you used *synthetic divison* to evaluate your polynomial, it would have been clearer to see how evaluating a polynomial and factorization are related.

Most students are acquainted with using synthetic division to divide polynomials, but only a few realize one of its original purposes was to facilitate polynomial evaluation. (In the context of polynomial evaluation, this is referred to as *Horner's rule*.)

Taking $P(x)=x^3 + 3x^2 - 13x - 15$ as the example, and supposing we wish to divide this by $x-2$, the synthetic division array will look like this:

$$\begin{array}{c|rrrr}2&1&3&-13&-15\\&&2&10&-6\\\hline&1&5&-3&-21\end{array}$$

What does this say? It means $P(2)=-21$, and it *also* means that

$$\frac{x^3 + 3x^2 - 13x - 15}{x-2}=x^2+5x-3+\frac{-21}{x-2}$$

So, you hit two birds with one stone in synthetic division. You evaluate the polynomial at a specific value, and you also see if the polynomial has the corresponding binomial as a factor.

Now, let's see what happens if we divide by $x+1$:

$$\begin{array}{c|rrrr}-1&1&3&-13&-15\\&&-1&-2&15\\\hline&1&2&-15&0\end{array}$$

which again means that $P(-1)=0$ **and**

$$\frac{x^3 + 3x^2 - 13x - 15}{x+1}=x^2+2x-15+\frac{0}{x-2}=x^2+2x-15$$